# Hashchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

So, there is something wrong with my hashchange... It wont trigger

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    var values = window.location.hash.slice(1).split('/');
    $("[name=" + values[0] + "]").val(values[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing `);` at the end of the second event handler assigment.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    '...';
}); //<= here you had only }
```

Other than that, it [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/w7Fnn/). Unless you are using IE7 of course, which does not support [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) ([browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange#Browser_compatibility)).

Comment: @user2128056 Always check the console of your browser, it will notify you about syntax errors like this ;).

Comment: or use JSHint / JSLint in your IDE :)